# Basic HTTP Authentication through JQuery / Javascript for Elastic Search

Tags: jquery, http, authentication, elasticsearch, typeahead.js

I'm using bloodhound to query search results from my elastic search server and they require me to do the HTTP basic Authentication? I'm facing problem in the code below that it does not authenticate me. My chrome pops up with the authentication window instead of doing it automatically. Server sends me 401 unauthorized error.

So my question is: How can I do the HTTP basic Authentication through javascript and in below code what am I doing wrong?

[image: Chrome error]

```
 var engine = new Bloodhound({
   name: 'history',
   limit: 10,
   datumTokenizer: function (datum) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum); },
   queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
   remote: {
      url: 'my_url/_search',           
      rateLimitWait: 300,
      prepare: function (query, settings) {
         settings.xhrFields= {
                         withCredentials: true
                     };

         settings.username= "xxx";
         settings.password= "xxx";

           settings.type = "POST";
           settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
           search_payload = {
             "username": "xxx",
             "password": "xxx",
             "fields": ["title","link"],
              "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                  .....
                }
              },
              "highlight": {
                "fields": {
                  .....
                }
              }
           }
           settings.data = JSON.stringify(search_payload);
           return settings;
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

So I added

```
settings.xhrFields= {
             withCredentials: true
           };
```

and

```
settings.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("username:password")};
```

and it worked :)